# How to know user banned my app push notification or removed it from iOS and Android device, real time?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

(Other similar questions are too old, and lack of answer in that age)
The app we made is a sub-system in our project. We have some really serious message need delivery to end user. Push message is just one of channels. We really need to be noticed if the user removed the app or banned push notification, then we can decide post message via email or SMS.

#### Is there any way to detect removing the app or banning push? And how?

PS: I know there were Feedback Server for iOS device two years ago. And, now, APNS will reply invalid token error code if token not valid. But, it looks like not real-time update. Because, After I removed the app, the push notification status is still OK.

Comment: The Apple feedback service will eventually tell you that you are sending to an invalid device, but if the user has simply turned off notifications you don't know.  There is also no guarantee that a push notification will be delivered even if the app is installed and notifications are enabled

Comment: I heard the Feedback service is merged into APNS. So, if the push token is invalid, you will be noticed in APNS response. But, it looks not real time.